# How to generate excel report in rails 3 and send it to email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-excel

I want to generate excel sheet from data in the database models

- I want the feature to custom headings
- I want to download from browser
- I want to send it to email

Is there any gem for doing this requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use axlsx gem for generating the xls documents

these are few links

https://github.com/randym/axlsx

http://axlsx.blog.randym.net/

http://rubygems.org/gems/axlsx

May this help you

Answer (score 1):

Try [axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx). It's a very good spread sheet generator.
Downloading and email can be done with Rails. No need for other gem.

Answer (score 0):

I work at Expected Behavior, and we've created a web app called DocRaptor that converts HTML to Excel. DocRaptor is a subscription based product, but we offer a free plan that allows users to create up to 5 documents per month.

Since you mention wanting custom headers, I figured it might be a good fit.

Here's a link to a Switch on the Code blog about using DocRaptor to generate Excel files:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-doc-raptor-to-create-excel-spreadsheets

And a link to DocRaptor's home page:

http://docraptor.com/